# In Microsoft CRM 2011, can you create custom address fields on the Account that are mapped back to the address entity?

Tags: entity, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have added a custom field to the Address entity.  The Account entity has a number of address fields (address1_x..) that eventually somehow map back to the actual Address entity.  I would like to add a custom "address1_" field to the Account entity and have it map back to the custom field I have added to the Address entity.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not natively. You'd have to develop a custom plugin or some other process to copy the field over.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I am aware (one of the many things I dislike about the way addresses are implemented in Dynamics CRM).

One option would be to create a new property on account that mirrors the property on the address e.g. on address you have new_newproperty and on account you also have new_newproperty.

Then using a plugins registered on Account Create, Account Update, Address Create and Address Update you could keep the values in sync by mirroring changes from one to the other.

Not ideal by any means.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.  Custom plugin it is.